# Как правильно преобразовать входные координаты старой матрицы в новую (сжатие матрицы)?

Tags: c

Столкнулся с проблемой: дана матрица `Matrix` размерности `DimX, DimY`, содержащая следующие элементы:

```
ОХОХОХОХ...
ХОХОХОХО
OXOXOXOX
...
```

где элемент `Х` либо `О` не используется. Для примера пусть `X` используется, а `O` - нет. Нам нужно убрать `O` и записать все `X` последовательно в новый массив.

Опытным путем я вычислил, что при сохранении `Х` кол-во элементов всегда равно половине элементов матрицы.

```
unsigned char* Rep = malloc(this->DimX*this->DimY>>1);  // собственно сюда нам нужно записать результат
```

По сути требуется сжать матрицу путем преобразования координат старой матрицы в новую (найти выражение, подставив в которое прежние координаты и длину старой матрицы мы получим новые координаты):

пример 1: координаты (4:1)

```
ОХОХОХОХ...
ХОХОНОХО     // в Н загоняется значение (4:1)->
OXOXOXOX
...
```

итоговая матрица без нулей выглядит так:

```
ХХХХ...
ХХНХ     //-> (2:1)
XXXX
...
```

***Необходимо :*** зная только `(x, y)` и длину старой матрицы (DimX) (где `x` - номер столбца, а `y` - номер строки) правильно преобразовать их в `(x', y')` - координаты сжатой матрицы. (например для `(4,1) -> (2:1)`).

Большую сложность представляет то, что выражение должно работать и для прежней матрицы и четной длины и нечетной и преобразовываться так:

для старой матрицы 7х3: (ХХХ)(ХХХХ)(ХХХ)

для старой матрицы 6х3: (ХХХ)(ХХХ)(ХХХ), где () - мнимая строка

Задание на экономию памяти, поэтому пересоздавать матрицу нельзя, нужно сохранять именно в конечном виде.

Comment: *Опытным путем я вычислил, что при сохранении Х кол-во элементов всегда равно половине элементов матрицы.* Только при условии, что хотя бы одно из измерений чётно - иначе половина не совсем целая получится... Остальное совершенно непонятно.

Comment: @Akina проще сказать x*y >> 1, что в остальном не понятно?

Comment: Опишите более конкретно, что вам дано и что нужно сделать. А то вопрос "Как запрограммировать матрицу-сетку?" совсем непонятен.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko переформулировал

Comment: @IlyaPakhmutov а как вы храните числа 10-16 в матрице типа char? В шестнадцатиричной форме?

Comment: @IlyaPakhmutov и что значит "пересоздавать матрицу нельзя"? Непонятно тогда, где сохранять ваш линейный массив.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko вообще в двоичной, числа от 0b0001 до 0b1111 и одно значение на провал - 16

Comment: @AndreiKhotko это не строка, просто ассемблерный тип байт здесь чар, мне приходится его использовать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91502/discussion-between-andrei-khotko-and-ilya-pakhmutov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ходе общения автор вопроса просил написать *функцию*, которая будет принимать `x` и `y` - номер строки и столбца элемента исходной матрицы `Matrix` и возвращать один индекс - индекс элемента в результирующем линейном массиве.

В конечном итоге, функция на Си будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
int GetLinearIdx(int x, int y)
{
    int x_idx = -1;

    if (y % 2 == 0) 
        x_idx = ((y >> 1) * col_count ) + (x >> 1); 
    else 
        x_idx = (y * (col_count >> 1)) + (x >> 1);

    return x_idx;
}
```

Сам автор преобразовал это выражение в `define`-конструкцию:

```
#define vectorSave(x,y) (!((y) % 2) ? (((y) >> 1) * dim) + ((x) >> 1) : ((y) * (dim >> 1)) + ((x) >> 1))
```

P.S. автор сам настоял на делении числа на два путем побитового сдвига.

**UPD:** в формулу прокралась ошибка, достаточно было написать

```
((y * this->DimX)>>1) + ((x) >> 1)
```

Comment: Стоит уточнить, что компиляторы сегодня и так умеют оптимизировать деление на 2 через сдвиг.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker это не для оптимизации, я работал с битами, поэтому мне требуется очень точно понимать что я делаю и на сколько кого сдвигаю